# Compressing static files not working on MVC and IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, compression

I'm trying to enable compression on my ASP.NET MVC 5 application that is hosted on IIS 7.5 and I can't make it work.

I have both static and dynamic compression enabled on the website.

I have tried adding the following to my web.config file:

```
<staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".js" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="text/javascript" />
</staticContent>

<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
    <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" staticCompressionLevel="9" />
    <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </dynamicTypes>
    <staticTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="text/javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>

<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
```